# Returning a list of strings from input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a function called, `getBASIC()`.  This is why I'm making this:

Write a function `getBASIC()` which takes no arguments, and does the following: it should keep reading lines from input using a while loop; when it reaches the end it should return the whole program in the form of a list of strings.

The program takes input in the form of:

```
X GOTO Y  
Y GOTO Z  
Z END
```

And so on and so forth.

My code for this is as follows:

```
def getBASIC():
   l = []
   while len(i.split()) == 3:
      i = input()
      l.append(i)
   return(l)
```

Problem is, I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`.  Now  I do know why this is, but I've suddenly become an idiot and can't figure out how to fix it.  Help debugging this would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about python, but putting something like `i = "A B C"` before the while loop should work, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution

```
   i = input()
   l.append(i)
   while len(i.split()) == 3:
       i = input()
       l.append(i)
```

other solution:

```
    while True:
        i = input()
        l.append(i)
        if len(i.split()) != 3:
            break
```

Comment: First solution is simply wrong. A line is consumed and gone forever. Second one is not elegant.

Comment: @mostruash: the 2nd solution is a common Python idiom to keep from repeating yourself. If it's any consolation, the compiled code in 3.x doesn't actually test the boolean value of built-in `True` on each pass. In practice it's a do-while loop.

Comment: Crap.  Sorry for not replying - I got sidetracked.  The first solution is incorrect (I know because I already tried that.)  Time to test the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def getBASIC():
   l = []
   x = 1
   while x == 1:
      i = input()
      l.append(i)
      if len(i.split()) != 3:
         x = 0
   return l
```